# What would be the Dual Expected Utility function for an English Auction?

Tags: auctions, expected-utility

So the DEU function is $$V(p)= \Sigma \,x_i\pi_i(p),$$ and since an auction only has two outcomes for a bidder, failure (with probability $p$) or success (probability $1-p$) the function becomes $$V(p)= x_1w(p) + x_2(1-w(p)).$$

But I'm not completely sure how to characterize the $x$'s. DEU being rank dependent, would the $x_1=0$ since it is a failure outcome and bidder doesn't get the item? If so, how would $x_2$ be described?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are more than two outcomes. One is losing the auction (not getting the good and not paying), and there is a different outcome for winning and paying a price p for each p lower than the bid.

Comment: so it would be (for valuation/resale price v and bid b) $\Sigma_{i=0}^b (v-i)\pi_i(p)$?

Comment: On second thought, wouldn't the winning bids be grouped in under the $x_2$, as that term has the probability weight of success, thus making that term (for bid b and valuation v) $\Sigma_{i=0}^b (v-i)(1-w(p))$?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the answer to your question depends a bit on what assumptions you want to make regarding bidder decision-making and behavior, and which additional axioms of choice you want your bidders to satisfy. For example, you could assume that your bidders consider the problem as a single stage, such that their utility can be defined as a vector of payoffs that depends on whether they win the object and how much they pay. (In that case, you'd have to consider more than just p and 1-p, and take the integral of probabilities of winning given a bidding function.) Alternatively, you could make an assumption on how individuals evaluate compound lotteries similar to that of compound independence from [Segal (1990)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2938207), which would allow you to model the "win/lose" and "payoff given price paid and auction won" separately.

While there isn't too much to go off of, I'd recommend looking into these papers that examine [payoff equivalence results under Dual Theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016517650200054X), as well as this [paper that models different auctions under Dual Theory](https://economics.smu.edu.sg/sites/economics.smu.edu.sg/files/economics/pdf/Seminar/2020/20201105.pdf) ([and the updated version](https://www.econ2.uni-bonn.de/moldovanu/revision18.pdf)  which seems to take the results in a slightly different direction, so both might be useful) and [this paper](https://www.econ2.jhu.edu/people/karni/ambiguity%20and%20nonexpected%20utility.pdf) which has a section describing how to apply non-expected utility theories to auctions. [Other papers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165176586900716?via%3Dihub), [like these](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/4778/2/450.pdf), develop models of auctions where bidders have reference-dependent preferences (though not necessarily Dual Theory utility functionals) and might also be helpful in figuring out the best approach. ([This one](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/345074064.pdf) briefly mentions non-expected utility applications to auctions--while not particularly helpful on its own, it includes a few references that might be of interest.)

Sorry I don't have a more definitive answer, but hopefully some of these resources can at least be useful in developing your model!